# Understanding Composition Function (fg)(-1) for f(x)=x-3 & g(x)=x^2-8x+15?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Can someone help explain how to do the following composition function to me? (or at least get me started)

Find the value of `(fg)(-1)` if `f(x) = x - 3` and `g(x) = x^2 - 8x + 15`

Is it simply plugging in the `-1` into the `f(x)` then using the result as the input value for `g(x)`? Ex:

$$f(-1) = (-1) - 3$$
$$f(-1) = -4$$
$$g(-4) = (-4)^2 - 8(-4) + 15$$
$$g(-4) = 16 + 32 + 15$$
$$g(-4) = 63$$

or would it be more like this:

$$(fg)(-1) = (x-3)(x^2 - 8x + 15)$$
$$(fg)(-1) = ((-1) - 3)((-1)^2 - 8(-1) + 15)$$
$$(fg)(-1) = ((-1) - 3)(1 + 8 + 15)$$
$$(fg)(-1) = ((-1) - 3)(24)$$
$$(fg)(-1) = -24 - 72 = -96?$$

Comment: The usual notation for function composition is "$f\circ g$" (read "$f$ following $g$"), which has the rule $(f\circ g)(x) = f( g(x) )$. If that's what you mean, you would first apply $g$ then apply $f$ to the result. But I have seen a multiplicative notation "$fg$" as you have written, which sometimes means "apply $f$, then apply $g$ to the result", which I never have liked. It isn't completely clear which you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the additional context [provided in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420270/understanding-composition-function-fg-1-for-fx-x-3-gx-x2-8x15/1420272?noredirect=1#comment2893858_1420272)$^1$, the notation means pointwise multiplication, that is
$$(fg)(x) := f(x) \cdot g(x)\\
(fg)(-1) = f(-1)\cdot g(-1) = -4\cdot 24 = -96$$
Similarly, you can define other pointwise operations as
$$\begin{align*}
(f/g)(x) &:= \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\\
(f+g)(x) &:= f(x) + g(x)\\
(f-g)(x) &:= f(x) - g(x)
\end{align*}$$
And composition is denoted by
$$(f\circ g)(x) := f(g(x))$$

$^1$*The answer was subsequently deleted, here is a copy of the comment for the <10k users:*
@AlexR I wasn't sure if the notation (fg)(-1) was the (f o g) notation or not. The problem next to it is (g/f)(2)... So then by your hint it would be the following?: g(-1) = (-1)^2 - 8(-1) + 15 = 25; f(25) = (25-3) = 22

Comment: Thanks Alex, but how did you get **-4 * 24 = -96**? I go **-4 * 15 = -60**.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic $g(-1) = (-1)^2 - 8 \cdot (-1) + 15 = 1 + 8 + 15 = 24$.